# Sonar #Gallio with NUnit 2.6.4

Tags: nunit, sonarqube, gallio

I have our Test Projects referncing to NUnit Framework ""
Getting the following error

```
Detected a probable test framework assembly version mismatch. 
Referenced test frameworks: 'nunit.framework, Version=2.4.6.0, Culture=neutral,         
PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77'.
Supported test frameworks: 'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.4.0-    2.5.65535.65535', 'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.0.0-2.5.3.65535'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a sonar issue. You have configured sonar to use a version of gallio that is not compatible with nunit 2.6.4 . You have two options. You can try to find another version of gallio that comes with nunit 2.6.4 or you can change your C# project in order to use nunit 2.5.4 instead of nunit 2.6.4 . The second solution is probably the easier one if you are not using advanced nunit features.